# Reuse Shiny progress bar from fileInput with bulma file upload

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, bulma

### Problem

I am setting up a Shiny up using `library(shinybulma)`.

In order to be consistent, I handcrafted a file input widget with the `bulma` classes. For a visual feedback I need  progressbar which is updated along the ulpoad process.

Looking at the source code from the [`fileInput` widget](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/f9a94d9758d298c2acfcdf8beeecc587ca534f0e/srcjs/input_binding_fileinput.js#L122), I see that I need a container with the `id` equal to the `id` of my widget appended by `_progress` and with classes `shiny-file-input-progress` and `progress-bar`.

In this way I can conveniently rely on Shiny to update the progress bar as we go along.

The devil, however, lies in the detail. My widget should optionally include up two 2 `bulma` buttons next to the `span.file-name`. The progress bar should always occupy the width defined by the elements in `div.file` (that is **including** optionally available buttons).

In order to get that work I had to hardcode `widths` and `min-widths` here and there which seems to me like a workaround which does not play well with the general `bulma` framework.

The `HTML` generated (with both optional buttons)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="field" style="width:440px">
  <label class="label">Label</label>
  <div class="file has-name">
    <label class="file-label">
      <input id="a" name="a" type="file" class="file-input"/>
      <span class="file-cta" style="min-width: 160px">
        <span class="file-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="file-label">Choose a file...</span>
      </span>
      <span class="file-name" style="width:100%; min-width:200px;">No file selected</span>
    </label>
    <a class="button    reset-file-form">
      <span class="icon  is-small">
        <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    <a class="button is-primary   remove-file-form">
      <span class="icon  is-small">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- normally the is-hidden class is added in this div and the color class would be has-background-light !-->
  <div id="a_progress" class="progress shiny-file-input-progress has-background-info"> 
    <div class="progress-bar has-background-info" style="padding-left:10px; font-size: 10px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this snippet the progress bar (which is shown in this snippet , but usually only shows up when an upload takes place) spans the right width, with the price that I have to hardcode `widths` and `min-widths` which are calculated depending of whether or not there are `buttons`.

The `min-width` should aslo guarantee that the `span.file-name` is not too short, when we upload a file with a very short file name.

### Question

How can I have the progress bar spanning the whole width of `div.file` without defining `width/min-width`? Ideally, this should be in the spirit of `bulma` i.e. using existing classes rather than defining inline css.

Answer (score 1):

From what is shown on your codebase, the row of the actions and the row of the progress bar are siblings, if they have a joint parent container that will accommodate the constraints of the width, and the progress bar sibling will flex to this container constraints, then you can probably remove all the internal width styling per each sibling and lay it all on the parent.

I ran a local POC of the code, it is lacking the fancy styles you are using since I'm not sure what all your CSS is doing under the hood, but I was able to remove all the `width` hard coded styles and set only one initial `width` at the top root that reflects its constraints on its children.

```
      <div class="field" style={{ width: "500px" }}>
        <label class="label">Label</label>
        <div>
          <div class="file has-name">
            <label class="file-label">
              <input id="a" name="a" type="file" class="file-input" />
              <span class="file-cta">
                <span class="file-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="file-label">Choose a file...</span>
              </span>
              <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
            </label>
            <a class="button    reset-file-form">
              <span class="icon  is-small">
                <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="button is-primary   remove-file-form">
              <span class="icon  is-small">
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div
            id="a_progress"
            class="progress shiny-file-input-progress has-background-info"
            style={{ padding: "15px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
          >
            <div
              class="progress-bar has-background-info"
              // style="padding-left:10px; font-size: 10px"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Feel free to let me know if that is what you were hoping for, or whether I can help with any other type of direction for the solution.

Comment: Hi Shimi, thanks for your answer. Well, this is not exactly what I was after. I was looking for a solution which fits in neatly with the `bulma` framework, that is avoiding manual `width` alltogether. But maybe the answer is I can't.

Comment: Best of luck buddy! I hope you'll find what you are looking for.